# Resizing / wrapping the content text when select dropdown is closed

Tags: html, css

so I have this issue which I feel like it should be simple enough, but for some reason I am stumped...

I have this select dropdown that looks like so:
[image]

When the screen size gets smaller, the content text is hidden the smaller the screen gets. Is there a way to make the text wrap, so that all of it displayed in the dropdown box?

The caret is a background image with absolute positioning, so I will need to add some padding between the caret and where the text ends, but I want to make the text wrap (*and the select box will become taller*) so that it all fits and is visible.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: This is part of a React app, with lots of different components coming into play in making the select dropdown (with the option values), so it would take a while to decouple the code to actually post what is being rendered. I was just thinking there was some CSS / media query rules I could implement; has been a while since I have worked with CSS, especially with default html select boxes...

Comment: Just looking for the simplest html select dropdown with an option value, that when selected, all of the text is displayed in the select box, wrapping to 2 or more lines as needed with the shrinking screen, instead of being cut off and hidden as the screen size gets smaller.

Comment: is it normal select with options or a select 2 plugin? because in both the case approach will be different

Comment: It just a normal select...